# RDS Snapshot Restore in AWS with Python BOTO3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

Here is my code to restore the rds instance from rds snapshot using python boto3

```
import boto3
x=input('Please enter the RDS Instance Name :')
z=input('Please enter the RDS Snapshot Name :')
y=input('Please enter the RDS Instance Class:')
a=input('Please enter the RDS Instance Subnet Group Name:')
client = boto3.client('rds', region_name='xxxxxxx')

rdsinstances = client.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot(DBInstanceIdentifier=x.strip(),DBSnapshotIdentifier=z.strip(),DBInstanceClass=y.strip(),DBSubnetGroupName=a.strip())
for i in rdsinstances['DBInstance']:
 print('Instance_name:' + i['DBInstanceIdentifier'])
 print('DB_Instance_Status:' + i['DBInstanceStatus'])
 print('DB_Instance_Class:' + i['DBInstanceClass'])
 print('DB_Subnet_Group:' + i['DBSubnetGroupName'])
```

My Code was able to restore the db instance from RDS Snapshot but the print output is failing at line 10.

`"TypeError: string indices must be integers".`

Can any one please let me know where I am doing wrong in calling the key and value for "restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot" module.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that `rdsinstances['DBInstance']` is an `dict`, but you are trying to iterate over it as though it is a `list`.